# Can we attach/send External file along with SSRS subscription report?

Tags: file, reporting-services, external, subscription

I have a SALES report which I send to users everyday using SSRS subscriptions (delivered by email.) My manager asked me to attach a external Word document along with this report.

So the user has to receive a) the SALES report and b) the external Word document.

Is it possible to attach/send an external document along with an SSRS subscription delivered by email?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Guys thanks for your response. I solved this by using send mail task of ssis.

step 1: I had created subscription for sales report to be delivered to windows file share.

step 2 : I had placed the external document at the same windows file share.

step 3: used ssis sendmail task to attach both the salesreport and external document to be sent to recipients.

It worked well!! :)

Answer (score 2):

Not through the SSRS subscriptions no, but you could write something that would render the sales report and email both files to the user(s)

Answer (score 1):

You can't do this through subscriptions. You need to write your own program to render the report and attach this to the email with your other attachments. It's not as hard as it sounds. The MSDN site [has some useful code](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/reportexecution2005.reportexecutionservice.render.aspx) that shows you how to render the report that will get you started.